# Sails.js adapter compatibility issue in sails 1.0

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, adapter

**I am using connect-mongo and sails-mongo module**
After installing **npm install sails-elastic@latest --save**
it still  shows error mentioned below
 throw flaverr('E_NOT_COMPATIBLE', new Error(
    ^

Error: 
-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-

The adapter used by the `sailsElastic` datastore is not compatible with
the current version of Sails/Waterline.

The adapter should expose a valid `adapterApiVersion`.

If you're using Sails ≥1.0, try:
npm install sails-elastic@latest --save

-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-
Please tag someone if you know who can answer